# I was trying to understand the concept of generators in python I am trying to implement it in different ways but i am getting stuck at one point

Tags: python, generator

For starters I wrote a code for generator to initially grasp the context

```py
def cycleoflife():
    # use yield to create a generator
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        yield "eat"
        yield "sleep"
        yield "code"
```

which printed

```
eat
sleep
code
```

on every next call

But I want to try something different so wanted to implement generator I named `Mary` such that it shows  string like these on every next call:

```
I love Mary 

Mary love that I love Mary

I love that Mary love that I love Mary

Mary love that I love that Mary love that I love Mary

I love that Mary love that I love that Mary love that I love Mary.....
```

```py
def Mary():
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        yield "I love Mary"
        yield "Mary love that"
        yield "I love that"

love = Mary()
```

This is my code I keep getting stuck on how to concatenate my calls in a loop such that I get the above result.

Comment: Each `yield` yields one thing.  If you want to do a reverse concatenate on the results, you'd do that in the function that CALLS `Mary`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you could implement this, although this is not really a good use case for a generator.  Note that `itertools.cycle` does exactly what your `Mary` function was doing.

```
from itertools import cycle
def Mary():
    parts = ["I love Mary", "Mary love that", "I love that"]
    hold = []
    for n in cycle(parts):
        hold.insert( 0, n )
        yield ' '.join(hold)

for s in Mary():
    print(s)
```

Comment: I guess the reason you said that this is not a good use case is because you could just return the `hold` list instead of yielding each value, thereby making the use of `yield` unnecessary?

Comment: Well, this is a fuzzy philosophical point.  The point of using a generator is that it should have to retain all that state.  It should just be generating the phrases.  It should be up to the user/caller to decide how to combine the results of the generator.

Comment: This is great i know cycle does the same but challenge was for using generator by the way i was told to do the same thing but now with changing capetalization like            I love you
You love that I love you
I love that you love that I love you                                                                                     here you can see the capitalization changes i tried to use the capitalize function but it didn't work

Comment: You would leave it lower case ("you") in your list, and then always uppercase the first letter of your response.  If it's already capital ("I", "Mary") it won't matter.